# Generate a random according to criteria

Tags: java, json, eclipse, arraylist, random

I have a JSON File (ArrayList) with some Restaurants and km(miles) from my Workplace to the Restaurant. The User can choose how far away the Restaurant should be (5km, 10km..) after that should the Applikation chooses the one Restaurant from the list, which inside this km is. So I need a random generator that, choose a Restaurant according to my criteria. The Result should show a Restaurant with "Name, Address, km, phone number and day offs".

Can someone support me? I'm new in this Business.

[image: JSON File]

[image: Main]

[image: AdapterJSON which reads data from JSON File]

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far as text here.

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Abra Yes i actually checked better, you are right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can:

- order your list by distance.
- filter items in the range needed
- create a random int between 0 and the size of the filtered items (minus 1)
- pick the filtered item in the random position

Comment: It would be useful to post a comment explaing why the minus.

Comment: Okay, if I ordered them by distance. Can I say too, show me just the Restaurant which is open in the specified radius? Do i have to do this in the "AdapterJSON" File oder in the "Main" File? Thanks for your Feedback!

Comment: Yes you can apply any filter to your data. You can order them by distance, remove if they are not in the range, remove the closed ones, filter by any other preferences and then pick between  the remainings.